# set data in vue based on other data

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have data in vue component which changes based on the select dropdown values. I want to change my other data in the same component based on these changes.

for example

```
  data: function()
  {
      return{
      page:'self-employed', //dynamic data bind with select element
      loan:this.page === 'self-employed' ? 'business-loan' : 'personal-loan',
  }
  }
```

i use conditional statement but it is not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loan` should be a computed property based on your other data :

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    page: 'self-employed', //dynamic data bind with select element
  }
},
computed: {
  loan() {
    return this.page === 'self-employed' ? 'business-loan' : 'personal-loan'
  }
}
```